# Is there a way to do confirmation of payment after explicit approval in adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I'm implementing a simple adaptive payment in the embedded flow with an explicit approval.

What suprises me is that when performing the explicit approval, that is, when the user logs in, it gets only the form with pay button. When clicking on pay, the transaction is done.

This is not how it should work for me. What I need is that at that point the user only does the approval, and explicitly confirms the transaction on my site (like it is described in express checkout flow).

Is this possible, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Adaptive Payments, but you should be able to specify a 'payment action', which you can subsequently set to 'Authorization'. Once you're happy with the charge, you would call the [DoCapture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoCapture) API which lets you capture the funds.

Note: Authorized funds are guaranteed up to 3 days. Beyond 3 days you would need to reauthorize (DoReauthorization) or capture it, but you'd lose the guarantee.

See also [Using Authorization & Capture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_authcapture) for general information on using authorization & capture within PayPal.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the effort, but I think that the problem is just that features like the one you're proposing are not offered by Adaptive Payments API operations.